# Searching for partial words on Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I have run into a pretty annoying problem on Safari on Mac. If I search for part of a word that doesn't start at the beginning of the word, Safari can't find it.

For example, the [COTS Demo Flight 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COTS_Demo_Flight_2) page on wikipedia has >50 counts of the word "flight", expectedly. If you hit cmd-F and then type in "flight", it works as expected and gives you a bunch of results. But if you type in "light" instead, then Safari would give you only 1 match, matching the whole word "light" somewhere in the article.

I am wondering if it is just me and if there are ways to fix this (maybe extensions?). Thanks!

btw, I am running Safari 5.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Click the magnifying glass symbol in the search input field and select *Contains*. By default, it's set to *Starts With*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of clicking the magnifying glass...

Comment: Damn you Safari!! This is totally screwed up UX.

Comment: Had my web team even change the Grid I was searching in...  Newman!